# Getting set of users attached to an object

Tags: python, html, django

Say I have an object Staffing which has a Project and User attached to it. I can get all staffing of a project by doing

```
{{project.staffing_set.all}}
```

But what I want is all Users that are staffed to that project. The above code will return a set of staffing objects, I want a set of users attached to those staffing objects. Any ideas?

Comment: please attach your models and any views you're using to represent the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define a method on Project that returns users.

```
def staffed_users(self):
    return User.objects.filter(staff__project=self)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in the template, you need to do it in views.py then return the value to the template:

```
staffings = project.staffing_set.all()
users = staffings.values_list('user', flat=True).distinct()
```